# How will the HTTP request be served in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Can you please explain me how the HTTP request will be served in servlet?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables

Comment: Please be more specific. "How" could mean many things, ranging through request interpreation, threading, business logic, response formatting, socket level network access, security, session management and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Every request get a new Thread to a instance of servlet. The servlet service methods DOGET OR DOPOST which takes the request and reads the request headers as to what all things a browser accepts. On the basis of request. The servlet creates a responses and send it to the client browser on the same thread.